# Codeigniter 3.1.8 JSON Post fails

Tags: json, postman, codeigniter-3

I am attempting a JSON POST request to a controller.

The header is: `[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json"}]`

I am trying a minimal payload: `{"user":1}`

According to multiple write ups I have tried the following:

```
public function authorize(){
    echo 'Line 37';
    print_r($this->input->raw_input_stream);//NULL
    print_r(json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream));//NULL
    print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));//NULL
    print_r(json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true));//NULL
    print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://in‌​put"), true));//file_get_contents(): Invalid php:// URL specified
}
```

But I get empty string for both var_dumps, string(0) "".

Any suggestions?

Comment: @pradeep I updated the info.
The is no post form, the payload is {"user":1} and headers as listed above. I use Postman to make the request.

Comment: post form means how u posting data, with ajax or curl or something else

Comment: I post the data with Postman.